# Paypal: No IPN notification on ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am not getting any IPN notification after successful Expresscheckout.
I have tried overwriting NOTIFY URL dynamically and by setting it through "My Setting tools" setting. But none of them hitting to url specified for IPN.
I am using sandbox accounts for making payments.

What is missing in here? Please help me out. Thanks in advance..!

This works perfectly fine if i use IPN Simulator for IPN testing...!

Comment: :( I am facing same problem. Why PayPal is not sending IPN message on completion of payment?

Comment: Where are you sending your response? When testing in the Sandbox, be sure to post your response to the correct URL, which is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr, instead of the live URL https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

Comment: Check your IPN history, where is it sending the data to? What are you doing with the IPN request? Express checkout should allow you to do process a transaction without IPN.

Comment: Yes, i have been using sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

@DavidNguyen: I have checked ipn history, it contains no history.
IPN message should come after successful payment completion.
Are you saying that IPN message will not come after express checkout?

Comment: I have tried changing variables used in name value pair during setexpress checkout and do express checkout methods, but none of it worked. Still not so sure why IPN is not get called after successful payment completion even for reuccuring payments. There is no IPN history. :(